# Python sklearn kaggle/titanic tutorial fails on the last feature scale

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

I was in the process of working through this tutorial: http://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-score-08134-in-titanic-kaggle-challenge.html

And it went with no problems, until I got to the last section of the middle section:

*As you can see, the features range in different intervals. Let's normalize all of them in the unit interval. All of them except the PassengerId that we'll need for the submission*

```
In [48]:
>>> def scale_all_features():

>>>     global combined

>>>     features = list(combined.columns)
>>>     features.remove('PassengerId')
>>>     combined[features] = combined[features].apply(lambda x: x/x.max(), axis=0)

>>>     print 'Features scaled successfully !'

In [49]:
>>> scale_all_features()
```

*Features scaled successfully !*

and despite typing it word for word in my python script:

```
#Cell 48
GreatDivide.split()
def scale_all_features():

    global combined

    features = list(combined.columns)
    features.remove('PassengerId')
    combined[features] = combined[features].apply(lambda x: x/x.max(), axis=0)

    print 'Features scaled successfully !'

#Cell 49
GreatDivide.split()
scale_all_features()
```

It keeps giving me an error:

```
--------------------------------------------------48--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------49--------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KaggleTitanic[2-FE]--[01].py", line 350, in <module>
    scale_all_features()
  File "KaggleTitanic[2-FE]--[01].py", line 332, in scale_all_features
    combined[features] = combined[features].apply(lambda x: x/x.max(), axis=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4061, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4157, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "KaggleTitanic[2-FE]--[01].py", line 332, in <lambda>
    combined[features] = combined[features].apply(lambda x: x/x.max(), axis=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 651, in wrapper
    return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 592, in na_op
    result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'", u'occurred at index Ticket')
```

What's the problem here? All of the previous 49 sections ran with no problem, so if I was getting an error it would have shown by now, right?

Comment: The *Ticket* column contains strings. So, normalizing them wouldn't just happen. Try, one hot encoding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help insure that the math transformation only occurs on numeric columns with the following.

```
numeric_cols = combined.columns[combined.dtypes != 'object']
combined.loc[:, numeric_cols] = combined[numeric_cols] / combined[numeric_cols].max()
```

There is no need for that apply function.

Comment: Got it. I'll see if this works and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Hey, everything *seems* to be working, thanks! I'll let you know if I run into any problems.